# If I am performing data preprocessing on training data, is it necessary to perform the same on test data?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, training-data, data-cleaning

For example, if I find the `mean` and `variance` of the training data and `normalize` it, should I use the same `mean` and `variance` for testing data or should I find the `mean` and `variance` of testing data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the mean and variance used on the **training data**. This ensures that the processing methodology on both sets of data is the same, the unseen (test) set data mean/variance should not be used.